# VIM taglist toggle on/off

Tags: vim, taglist

I'm using taglist in VIM and i have remapped F12 so that it will call :TaglistToggle

```
nnoremap <F12> :TaglistToggle
```

is there a way that i can hit F12 and it will toggle the list on/off without having to hit return.

At the moment F12 will just place the command TaglistToggle in the command buffer and then i have to hit return to carry out the command.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

put `<CR>` (which is interpreted as carriage return) behind it:

```
nnoremap <F12> :TaglistToggle<CR>
```

Comment: That was simple, Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can include keystrokes in the command as well:

```
nnoremap <F12> :TaglistToggle<enter>
```